# JavaScript inflate implementation (possibly FF 3.6 only)

Tags: javascript, firefox, compression, deflate

I'm writing some scripts that are using the HTML 5 file API in FireFox 3.6. I got some deflated (compressed) files, and I need to inflate (uncompress) them.

I found a [few](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Javascript_binaryenc.aspx) [scripts](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/amuse/javascript/expert/inflate.txt) while googling, but none of them have tests. So I'm a bit reluctant to use them.

My question is: Browsers can inflate. **Can I somehow piggyback on the inflation by forging A XHR request?** Or piggyback in any other way? Keep in mind, the script is currently FireFox 3.6 exclusive. It can't be an extension, though, I want it to be a regular webpage.

**Alternatively**, are there any scripts that you know of that has tests written for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [an existing library](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/amuse/javascript/expert/inflate.txt). Wrote a test. Wrapped it in a function so that it didn't pollute the global namespace, that's about it.

http://github.com/augustl/js-inflate

Answer (score 0):

Update of my post is:
http://pastie.org/1588170

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

I use DEFLATE encoder and decoder implementation in Javascript at http://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate

I use Google's V8 Javascript engine (url  ) on server side to run Javascript code which I run on client side in web browser.